# prestashop 1.6 add new attribute

Tags: php, attributes, uri, prestashop

I'm trying to add new product in my `Prestashop store` ,

*but I want to add new attributes and set there values*

I have no idea for how can I do this , any body have example for how can I add new attribute in my Prestashop store ," URI!!!"

Answer (score 2):

Adding attributes and their values is easy.

1. Go to `Back office > Catalog > Product attributes`
2. Add your new attributes
3. At the top /right corner, click on button "+ Add new value".

Complete the form with asked information. 
That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Login to back office > Catalog > Products
Here you can add a new product by clicking (+) symbol on top-right side of your existing products. (There might be some test products in list, which comes with default prestashop installation)

- First you have to save the product with some basic and mandatory info (eg. name and all)
- Then you may add attributes in combinations (eg. Pack Size, Weight etc.)

Comment: thank you Anil for your response , i find the answer for this section using api call ;)

Comment: great, also if you are adding the attributes for bulk products you may use CSV import function of prestashop.